# How to unit test Date in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, tdd

If I have ArticleItem struct like this:

```
public struct ArticleItem: Equatable {
    public let id: UUID
    public let description: String?
    public let location: String?
    public let thumbnailURL: URL
    public let created: Date

    public init(id: UUID, description: String?, location: String?, thumbnailURL: URL, created: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.description = description
        self.location = location
        self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
        self.created = created
    }

}
```

But from back-end we would receive such info:

```
{
    "id": "a UUID",
    "description": "a description",
    "location": "a location",
    "image": "https://a-image.url",
    "created_date": "2020-05-09",
}
```

How can I test the correctness of Date ?

In the test I have something like this:

```
 func test_load_deliversItemsOn200HTTPResponseWithJSONItems(){
         let (sut, client) = makeSUT()

        let item1 = ArticleItem(id: UUID(), description: nil, location: nil, thumbnailURL: URL(string: "http://a-url.com/")!, created: Date())

        let item1JSON = [
            "id": item1.id.uuidString,
            "image": item1.imageURL.absoluteString,
            "created_date": ??? // what should be here
            ]

        let items = [
            "items": [item1JSON]
        ]

        expect(sut: sut, toCompleteWithResult: .success([item1])) {
            let itemsJSON = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: items)
            client.complete(withStatusCode: 200, data: itemsJSON)
        }

     }
```

I've heard about using `iso8601` when decoding but still don't know how to do it.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What are you going to test here? Why not set date to a hardcoded value with the same format as in the received json, e.g "2020-05-09"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what do you mean by set date to a hardcoded value ? Can you please have an example.

Comment: But I gave you one in the comment, `"created_date": "2020-05-09"`

Comment: Does that mean when I create `item1` I should inject `created` value is a hardcoded Date object of `2020-05-09` instead of Date()

Comment: That is my suggestion but you haven't explained exactly what you are testing? If you only want to test that the json is properly decoded into a date then it should fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the decoder what `dateDecoderStrategy` your model or json follows.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(TheFormatThatTheDateHas)
```

and then

```
decoder.decode........
```

for the format, google the date plus with format.